# Am I configuring message and ksql keys correctly to ensure my final aggregation is correct?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a topic which is populated by the JDBC connector. It seems to have no kafka message key:

```
ksql> print 'mssql-transaction-log' limit 3;
Format:AVRO
3/6/20 11:40:35 AM UTC, null, {"TransID": 8789405114, "UserID": 15, "ActionCode": 80, "GameName": "thisgame", "GameID": 148362, "DataCashRef": null, "Success": "Y", "StartBalance": 188036, "Amount": -25, "EndBalance": 188011, "BonusSta
rtBalance": 10000, "BonusAmount": 0, "BonusEndBalance": 10000, "Stamp": 1583162921467, "SiteID": 6}
```

I have created a stream from this:

```
CREATE STREAM TRANSACTIONS_LOG_RAW
   (
      TRANSID BIGINT,
      USERID INTEGER,
      ACTIONCODE INTEGER,
      GAMENAME STRING,
      GAMEID BIGINT,
      DATACASHREF STRING,
      SUCCESS STRING,
      STARTBALANCE INTEGER,
      AMOUNT INTEGER,
      ENDBALANCE INTEGER,
      BONUSSTARTBALANCE INTEGER,
      BONUSAMOUNT INTEGER,
      BONUSENDBALANCE INTEGER,
      STAMP BIGINT,
      SITEID INTEGER
  )
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='mssql-transaction-log',
    VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO',
    KEY='USERID');
```

I have created a filtered stream from this one:

```
CREATE STREAM GAME_PURCHASES_RAW AS
    SELECT USERID,
    GAMENAME,
    AMOUNT,
    STAMP,
    TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(STAMP, 'yyyyMMddHH') HOUR_DIMENSION,
    TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(STAMP, 'yyyyMMdd') DAY_DIMENSION
    FROM TRANSACTIONS_LOG_RAW
    WHERE ACTIONCODE = 80
    PARTITION BY USERID;
```

When I inspect these messages, there is no kafka key:

```
ksql> print 'GAME_PURCHASES_RAW' limit 3;
Format:AVRO
3/6/20 11:40:35 AM UTC, null, {"USERID": 58, "GAMENAME": "game", "AMOUNT": -50, "STAMP": 1583162898780, "HOUR_DIMENSION": "2020030215", "DAY_DIMENSION": "20200302"}
3/6/20 11:40:35 AM UTC, null, {"USERID": 191, "GAMENAME": "game", "AMOUNT": -10, "STAMP": 1583162898780, "HOUR_DIMENSION": "2020030215", "DAY_DIMENSION": "20200302"}
3/6/20 11:40:35 AM UTC, null, {"USERID": 70, "GAMENAME": "game", "AMOUNT": -10, "STAMP": 1583162898980, "HOUR_DIMENSION": "2020030215", "DAY_DIMENSION": "20200302"}
```

When I describe the stream, it shows a key:

```
ksql> describe GAME_PURCHASES_RAW;

Name                 : GAME_PURCHASES_RAW
 Field          | Type
--------------------------------------------
 ROWTIME        | BIGINT           (system)
 ROWKEY         | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
 USERID         | INTEGER          (key)
 GAMENAME       | VARCHAR(STRING)
 AMOUNT         | INTEGER
 STAMP          | BIGINT
 HOUR_DIMENSION | VARCHAR(STRING)
 DAY_DIMENSION  | VARCHAR(STRING)
--------------------------------------------
For runtime statistics and query details run: DESCRIBE EXTENDED <Stream,Table>;
ksql>
```

I am going to create an aggregate from this GAME_PURCHASES_RAW stream grouping by USERID. I thought for aggregates, the kafka message key cannot be null because I need to keep messages for each unique USERID on the same partition.

Why does the stream for GAME_PURCHASES_RAW not show the key in the kafka message for the topic it creates?

Am I configuring message and ksql keys correctly to ensure my final aggregation is correct?

(I suspect my understanding of kafka keys vs ksql stream keys is lacking at some fundamental level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have set `KEY='USERID'` in the `WITH` clause of `TRANSACTIONS_LOG_RAW`.  Remove this and it will work.

Setting a `KEY` informs KSQL that the data in the specified column is the same as the data in the row's key. But this is not the case! The key in the raw log is `null`.

When you later `PARTITION BY USERID`, ksqlDB does not repartition your data and set the key, as you've told it the data is already partitioned by `USERID`.

You're not alone in making this mistake. The use of `KEY` in the `WITH` clause is common cause of confusion, which is why we're removed it in later releases. You've on quite an old version there. A lot has changed, and been improved, since that version. I'd recommend upgrading!

Comment: We'd been putting off upgrading but it really isn't that scary at all, cheers Andy!